# characteristic function of product of two random variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, expected-value, characteristic-functions

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $N(0,1)$ iid R.V.s.

Compute the characteristic function of $Y=X_1X_2$.

***Solution:***

For a R.V. X the characteristic function is defined as: $\varphi_X(s)=E[e^{isX}]$.

$\varphi_Y(s)=\varphi_{X_1X_2}(s)=E[e^{isY}]=E[e^{isX_1X_2}]$

*Law of total expectation*: $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$, where X,Y are two R.V.s defined on the same probability space. [//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$E[e^{isX_1X_2}]=E[E[e^{isX_1X_2}|X_2]]=E[\varphi_{X_1}(sX_2)]$

$X_1\in N(0,1)$

The characteristic function $\varphi(s)$ for a $N(0,1)$ distributed R.V. is $\varphi(s)=e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}$.

$\varphi_{X_1}(s)=e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}$. So, $\varphi_{X_1}(sX_2)=e^{-\frac{(sX_2)^2}{2}}=e^{-\frac{s^2X_2^2}{2}}$.

$E[\varphi_{X_1}(sX_2)]=E[e^{-\frac{s^2X_2^2}{2}}]$

**(This next step I don't understand.)**

$E[e^{-\frac{s^2X_2^2}{2}}]=(X_2\in N(0,1))=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Re}e^{-\frac{s^2x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$

(the pdf of $X_2$ is given by $f_{X_2}(x_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$). It seems to me as if the formula: $E[g(X)]=\int_\Omega g(x)f_X(x)\ dx$ has been used to calculate the expectation $E[e^{-\frac{s^2X_2^2}{2}}]$, i.e. $E[g(X_2)]=\int_\Re g(x_2)f_{X_2}(x_2)\ dx_2 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\Re}e^{-\frac{s^2x^2}{2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$. **First, why do they use $x$ in the solution, instead of $x_2$ (like I just did in this paragraph)?**. **Second, mustn't one account for the fact that we have two variables in the expectation, namely: $X_2\ and\ s$**. The formula seem to have been used ignoring the variable $s$. Can someone explain why this is and why it is allowed?

Comment: What do you mean “account for [...] two variables”? If you have a function $h(z,s)$ of two variables and set $Y=h(Z,s)$ for some RV $Z$ with density $f_Z(z)$ and a *fixed real* $s$ then $\mathbb{E}(Y)=\mathbb{E}(h(Z,s)) =\int h(z,s) f_Z(z) dz=:\psi(s)$ by LOTUS and is a function of the fixed variable $s$.

Comment: @NapD.Lover The formula in the books is expressed as $E[g(X)]=...$ but, in the problem we transform using characteristic function so that we have a function $g(X,s)$ i.e. of two variables. The formula in the books is expressed as $g(X)=...$ and now all of a sudden I had $g(X,s)$, so I became uneasy about whether or not the formula could be used.

Comment: there is only *one source of randomness*, so with $s$ fixed, LOTUS can be applied to $g(X):=\tilde{g}(X,s)$. Treat $s$ like a constant. However one gets a different value of $\mathbb{E}(g(X))$ for each input of $s$ so it is actually a function of $s$ at the end. It’s no different than writing something like $f(s):=\int_0^1 s x dx =s/2$. You integrate out one variable and are left with an expression in terms of the fixed variable.

Answer (score 2):

As the original question started out, if $X_i$ are iid $N(0,1)$ rvs, and $Y=X_1X_2$ then then (using the law of total expectation) the characteristic function $$\varphi_Y(s)= E[\exp(is X_1 X_2)] = E[\exp(-s^2X_2^2/2)]=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-x_2^2/2} e^{-s^2x_2^2/2}\,dx_2.
$$
(Here the dummy variable of integration is $x_2$ because it corresponds to the rv $X_2$, but of course any symbol would do.)  To finish  the problem we only need to work out the integral.

If you make the change of variables $x_2=\frac 1{\sqrt{1+s^2}} u$, so the quadratic term in the exponent of the last integral becomes $-u^2/2$, the integral reduces to $$\varphi_Y(s)= \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+s^2}}  \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\mathbb R} e^{-u^2/2}\,du = \frac 1 {\sqrt{1+s^2}}.$$